# Creating a 2d matrix from an array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, 2d

I'm supposed to write a method that creates a 2d matrix from an array, for instance: ({1, 2, 3, 4}, 3) should return the matrix {{1, 2, 3}, {4}}

```
public class Matrix {
  public static int[][]toM(int[] array, int a) {
    int[][]matrix = new int [(array.length + a- 1)/ a][a];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      int value = array[i];
      value = value++;
      for (int row = 0; row < (array.length + a- 1)/a; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < a; col++) {
          matrix[row][col]= value++;
        }
      } 
    }
    return matrix;
  }
}
```

a is the number of elements in each row. how am i supposed to get [[1, 2, 3], [4]] if my input is int[] array = {1,2,3,4} and int n =3? I'm getting [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]?

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: That doesn't look like any 2D matrix that I've encountered.

Comment: Is this homework?

and I don't think you have fully specified the question.

Turn an array into a partial matrix of a given width filling from the top left across and then down?

Comment: a is the number of elements in each row. how am i supposed to get [[1, 2, 3], [4]] if my input is int[] array = {1,2,3,4} and int n =3?

Comment: You should edit your question and add what you just wrote in case someone doesn't look at the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is a little too far off base to easily repair. For starters, a three-level nested loop is completely unnecessary; also, you don't fetch array elements by writing `value++` (maybe you are getting confused with the C convention of using `*ptr++` to walk an array). Start again from first principles.

I'm assuming this is homework, so I'm not going to just write it for you. But here's the basic outline. The number of result elements depends on the input array rather than the dimensions of the output matrix, so your algorithm should loop over the input elements. For each element, some basic math on its index, `i`, will tell you where it belongs (`row` and `col`) in the output matrix. Assign `array[i]` to `matrix[row][col]`.

For bonus points, note that the last row is often shorter than the other rows. Allocating `matrix = new int [...][a]` will produce `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 0, 0]]` instead of the stated requirement. Fix this by allocating just the outer array of arrays — `matrix = new int [...][]` — and allocating each sub-array individually, making a special case of the last row using modulus arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this is a lot more readable:

```
static int[][] transform(int[] arr, int N) {
    int M = (arr.length + N - 1) / N;
    int[][] mat = new int[M][];
    int start = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < M; r++) {
        int L = Math.min(N, arr.length - start);
        mat[r] = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, start, start + L);
        start += L;
    }
    return mat;
}
```

Your resulting matrix will be `MxN`, with the last row possibly having less. It uses [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) instead of manually allocating and copying rows, and some math to figure out `M` (how many rows will this matrix have?), and `L` (how many elements will be on this row?)

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(
        transform(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6}, 4)
    )); // prints "[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is closer to what you have in mind:

```
public static int[][] toM2(int[] array, int a) {
    int[][] matrix = new int [(array.length + a- 1)/ a][a];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) matrix[i/a][i%a] = array[i];
    return matrix;
}
```

The line `int value = array[i]` followed by `value++` indicate that you are thinking about this problem like a C programmer.   The `array[i]` does not give you a pointer to a value, it just gives you a value.

So, the key is to take the index and transform it into row and column references:

```
int row = i/a;
int col = i%a;
```

There is still the problem of the rows all being the same length.  With java you don't have to allocate all the rows at the same time.  In fact, you can a new array for each row.  The following is complicated, but it works:

```
public static int[][] toM3(int[] array, int a) {
    int[][] matrix = new int[(array.length + a - 1) / a][];
    int rowStart = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int row = i/a;
        if (matrix[ row ] == null) {
            matrix[ row ] = new int[ Math.min( a, array.length-rowStart) ];
            rowStart += a;
        }
        matrix[ row ][i % a] = array[i];
    }
    return matrix;
}
```